# Multiline label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a multiline label but as the control is browser dependent, even on setting the height, width and wrap properties of the label control I am unable to display multiline text It doesn't support every browser in the same way.

Comment: What control are you talking about, exactly? How are you using it, what do you see, what did you expect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean `asp:Label` then it resolves to a `span` element in HTML output. It is neither single-line or multiline.

Define some fixed width for this element and the text will wrap into several lines when it's long enough.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" style="width:300px;">
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `CssClass` instead of inline

Answer (score 15):

You can concatenate the string in `asp:label` with `"<br/>"` because it will result in html.

For Example:

```
label1.Text = strSample1 & "<br/>" & strSample2
```

If you don't specific the width of label, it will auto expand the width to fit your string.

Comment: Following your example this worked for me :
`lblTest.Text = lblTest.Replace("\n", "<br/>");`

Answer (score 4):

Labels are single line by default.

But if you want to display multiple lines in a text box, then there is one option that might work.
I could not get autowrap to work, but if you want specific line breaks to occur, then

```
label.text = string1 + "<br/>" + string2 + "<br/>" + string3;
```

It may seem simple, but the C# `Environment.Newline` did not work in aspx.
Only rendering the `<br/>` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
width ="...px"  style="word-wrap:normal; "
```

If you want to break last word if it exceeds width then `style="word-wrap:break-word; "`
You can use  max-width:...px; on style tag for being sure word wrapping if you change width programmaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with "maximunsize" and "autosize" label properties and your problem is solved:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" style="width:300px;" maximunsize="300px" autosize="true">
```