# displaying label values in multiline text from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, label

I got one `gridview` which has `hyperlink` in one column, when the user clicks the link he will be directed to another page where the details of particular row will be displayed using individual labels. In those `labels` one of the label must be multilined for me because the text will be too long...

Please help me how to get that.

aspx page of label

```
<asp:Label ID="LblDescription" runat="server" 
Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#0061C1" Height="16px"
Width="97px" BorderColor="#0061C1" 
BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717190/multiline-label-in-asp-net).

Comment: thnks for replyng with tht post but i want my label to b in same size of othr labels... so i cant take the width property and format it..

Comment: Here is a [css solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16663014/451518) in a very similar question.

Comment: welll got break wid line but vertically text is goin out of label nw.. earlier it was horizontally :)

Comment: Do you really need to specify `Height` for your label? Try to remove `Height="16px"` from label declaration.

Comment: thnks mate... tht worked fine... plz make it as ur answer... will accpt it...

Comment: nvm, good luck! I'll mark it as a duplicate to help future users. Possible duplicate of [Make label multiline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662369/make-label-multiline)

Comment: yeah sure... thnk u ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="User1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"
       Width="300px" Text="I got one gridview which has hyperlink in one column, when the user clicks the link he will be directed to another page where the details of particular row will be displayed using individual labels. In those labels one of the label must be multilined for me because the text will be too long">
</asp:Label>
```

Setting the width property of label, will make the text multilined and the font size will remain the same, unless you specify the font name same for all the lables

Comment: renuka ji thnks for d reply... bt wat i need is my label shuldnt get altered with d size frm othr labels and im retriving d text for tht particular label frm database ... neways i gt d solution... :)

Comment: apke answer k liye bahut bahut dhanyavadh :)